# findresource without an application

Tags: c#, windows, resource-files

I've written an c# Console application, and I want to take advantage of resources management (resx files in a project).
Obviously, first the Current application need to be set, and I have none since it is a Console application.

Does anyone have thoughts about how to get resources in a console application?

Comment: Yes seems like a duplicate. If not, please elaborate.

Comment: My question was more about how to access dynamically resources properties. But pointers are indeed useful to answer my own question.